# Multiple sudo commands in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

After some reading I finally found out how to do sudo commands through cocoa. But when I try to do multiple commands, it only does the first one. My code:

```
AuthorizationRef authorizationRef;
OSStatus status;

status = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment,
                             kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &authorizationRef);

/* Step one: Rename current trash icon files */
// Rename trashempty icon
NSLog(@"Renaming trashempty icon");
char *trashempty_tool = "/bin/mv";
char *trashempty_args[] = {"/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/trashempty.png","/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/trashempty_backup.png"};

status = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(authorizationRef, trashempty_tool,
                                            kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, trashempty_args, NULL);

NSLog(@"Authorization Result Code: %d", status);
// Check for status TODO

NSLog(@"Renaming trashfull icon");
char *trashfull_tool = "/bin/mv";
char *trashfull_args[] = {"/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/trashfull.png","/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/trashfull_backup.png"};

status = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(authorizationRef, trashfull_tool,
                                            kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, trashfull_args, NULL);

NSLog(@"Authorization Result Code: %d", status);
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Need more than "it only does one".  What actually happens? What status do you get back from each `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges`?

Comment: Alright i added some NSLog lines which prints the status code. The first returns 0 and the second one returns -2129264641

Comment: What rights are you authorizing?  The above code snippet shouldn't allow you to execute anything with privileges.  Also, I would try to avoid `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` entirely.

Comment: The above code lets me copy/delete/rename files in the system folder. And that's what i need. The only problem is that i can only do 1 thing. In the above example, it will only let me rename the first file..

Comment: No, you really don't *need* that.  You should never *ever* be futzing with stuff in the `/System/` folder.  Not Ever.

Comment: I can't seem to find any other way to change the trash-icon. How would you suggest?

Comment: It also looks like the famous CandyBar app for changing system icons does the exact same thing according to their FAQ: http://www.panic.com/candybar/support.html - so yes, i need that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended that you create a helper app placed in your main bundle resource ,

I.e You put the Mv code in the helper app,
And use the Authorization in the main app to run it.

Doing so will give the helper app the permission to run with auth.
And it will be easier to write the code for the MV.
You can if you want use NSTask to do the MV job in the helper app.

You get the path of the helper app and convert it for the arg like this.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString * helpPath  =[[bundle resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/HelperApp" ];

const char *helperPath;
helperPath  = [helpPath cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and call helperPath in the AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges

Apple have example of how to go about this in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

with apple script:

NSAppleScript* script = [[[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"do shell scritp \"echo Larcus94\""] autorelease];
    NSDictionary* errorDict;
    [script executeAndReturnError:&errorDict];

with nstask (nicer way):

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/bash"];

NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-l", @"-a", @"-t", nil];
[task setArguments: arguments];

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString *string;
string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: NSTask is in no way helpful when executing a command with privileges.

Comment: Then use NSApplescript. NSAppleScript* script = [[[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"do shell scritp \"echo Larcus94\""] autorelease]; NSDictionary* errorDict; [script executeAndReturnError:&errorDict];